# How to customize the Android4.0 's LockScreen Using Opengl ES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, lockscreen

After developing the Android LiveWallPaper with Opengl ES and NDK programming I am trying to customize the Android's LockScreen. I know that the we can customise the LockScreen by modifying the source code at

```
frameworks/base/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/LockScreen.java
```

I figured out that we should overwrite the Class "MultiWaveView". But I found few people mentioned that using Opengl ES to do the animations. What I want to know is: Is it possible to use Opengl ES here? Is it a common way to do that? Does anyone have successful experiences?  Should I give up the thought of using Opengl ES？Any discussion or advice is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot experiences with changing default LockScreens on different Android version, but without OpenGL.
Anyway MultiWaveView just extends the View class. I believe that only you need is extends GLSurfaceView and use your own view instead of MultiWaveView.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to replace the Android lock screen (KeyGuard).

You can however disable the KeyGuard and display any Activity (and view) that you would like.  So yes, you can use an OpenGL view or any other view for that matter.

To do this just handle `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD` and/or `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` correctly for the Activity you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use OpenGL in the Lock screen:
[How to show SurfaceView on Lock Screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797906/how-to-show-surfaceview-on-lock-screen/13866500#13866500)

However, you can not make the lock screen part of an apk, in that case you need to fake the home screen.